# Подключить iPSEC Site to Site VPN без физического оборудования

Tags: linux, сеть, vpn

Всем привет, есть задача подключиться к site to site vpn, но поставить физическое оборудование для этого, firewall / vpn нет возможности.

Возможно ли программным способом без железа, таких как firewall и роутер, сделать подключение site to site vpn ?

Comment: Да, возможно. Если 2 хоста имеют общую среду в виде инета + статичные _публичные_ IP адреса, то я бы порекомендовал глянуть в сторону IPSec тунелей.  https://www.freebsd.org/doc/ru_RU.KOI8-R/books/handbook/ipsec.html для общего просвещения.

Comment: И да, если нужно просто гнать трафик через single host не подразумевая локальные машины, то я бы крайне порекомендовал не замарачиватся и использовать обычные ssh-тунели, эффект тот же но "малыми" средствами с минимум телодвижений.